# How can I pass the output that is a list of a function into a variable that I can use in other functions?

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a function that prints out a list

```
def make_list():
    print(['p','r','t','z'])
```

where I get the list ['p','r','t','z'] in output, but I would like to call this value in another function.
Lets say I want to add it to another list.

I was thinking

```
t = make_list

def append_list():
    t.append('u')
```

Comment: use `return` not `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def make_list():
    return ['p','r','t','z']

your_list = make_list()
```